# No signature of method android() is applicable for argument types

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried all solutions given over the web nothing worked.
Please Help as soon as possible.
Sync Error:

Build file 'C:\Users\AH_GL\Desktop\apps-android-commons\app\build.gradle' line: 149

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_bacf6ncg9oj63qiyhi1id1rfi.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_bacf6ncg9oj63qiyhi1id1rfi$_run_closure2) values: [build_bacf6ncg9oj63qiyhi1id1rfi$_run_closure2@733e2c45]

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version '2.7.2' apply false
}
apply from: '../gitutils.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "com.hiya.jacoco-android"
apply from: 'quality.gradle'

def isRunningOnTravisAndIsNotPRBuild = System.getenv("CI") == "true" && file('../play.p12').exists()

if (isRunningOnTravisAndIsNotPRBuild) {
    apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':wikimedia-data-client')
    // Utils
    implementation 'in.yuvi:http.fluent:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OKHTTP_VERSION"){
        force = true //API 19 support
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-support-v4:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-design:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'

    // UI
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pedrovgs:renderers:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.2'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization-v8:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-scalebar-v9:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates4-kotlin-dsl-layoutcontainer:$ADAPTER_DELEGATES_VERSION"
    implementation "com.hannesdorfmann:adapterdelegates4-pagination:$ADAPTER_DELEGATES_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$PAGING_VERSION"
    testImplementation "androidx.paging:paging-common-ktx:$PAGING_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2-ktx:$PAGING_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:$OKHTTP_VERSION"

    // Logging
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra-dialog:5.3.0'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra-mail:5.3.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    api('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$OKHTTP_VERSION"

    // Dependency injector
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    //Mocking
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"

    // Unit testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$OKHTTP_VERSION"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
    testImplementation "com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:1.1.2"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1"
    testImplementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0'

    // Mockito and PowerMock
    androidTestImplementation ('org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.0') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }

    // Android testing
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.8.0'
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'

    // Debugging
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$LEAK_CANARY_VERSION"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$LEAK_CANARY_VERSION"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$LEAK_CANARY_VERSION"

    // Support libraries
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$CORE_KTX_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

    //swipe_layout
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$ROOM_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$ROOM_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$ROOM_VERSION"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$ROOM_VERSION"
    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"

    // Pref
    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$PREFERENCE_VERSION"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$PREFERENCE_VERSION"

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$MULTIDEX_VERSION"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId 'fr.free.nrw.commons'
        versionCode 876
        versionName '3.0.0'
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "app-commons-v$versionName-" + getBranchName())

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'

        multiDexEnabled true

        testOptions {
            execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.*'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true

        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        // use kotlin only in tests (for now)
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'

        // use main assets and resources in test
        test.assets.srcDirs += 'src/main/assets'
        test.resources.srcDirs += 'src/main/resoures'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            testProguardFile 'test-proguard-rules.txt'
            if (isRunningOnTravisAndIsNotPRBuild) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled project.hasProperty('coverage')
            proguardFiles getDefaulProguardtFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            testProguardFile 'test-proguard-rules.txt'
            versionNameSuffix "-debug-" + getBranchName()
        }
    }

    if (isRunningOnTravisAndIsNotPRBuild) {
        // configure keystore based on env vars in Travis for automated alpha builds
        signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file("../nr-commons.keystore")
        signingConfigs.release.storePassword = System.getenv("keystore_password")
        signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = System.getenv("key_alias")
        signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = System.getenv("key_password")
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
        exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {

            applicationId 'fr.free.nrw.commons'

            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_API_POTD", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=featuredfeed&feed=potd&feedformat=rss&language=en\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_API_HOST", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_API_HOST", "\"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_URL", "\"https://www.wikidata.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_FORGE_API_HOST", "\"https://tools.wmflabs.org/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_CAMPAIGNS_URL", "\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commons-app/campaigns/master/campaigns.json\""
            buildConfigField "String", "IMAGE_URL_BASE", "\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons\""
            buildConfigField "String", "HOME_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "COMMONS_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_URL", "\"https://www.wikidata.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MOBILE_HOME_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SIGNUP_LANDING_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CreateAccount&returnto=Main+Page&returntoquery=welcome%3Dyes\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SIGNUP_SUCCESS_REDIRECTION_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&welcome=yes\""
            buildConfigField "String", "FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:PasswordReset\""
            buildConfigField "String", "PRIVACY_POLICY_URL", "\"https://github.com/commons-app/commons-app-documentation/blob/master/android/Privacy-policy.md\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CONTRIBUTION_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.contributions.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MODIFICATION_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.modifications.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CATEGORY_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.categories.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "RECENT_SEARCH_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.explore.recentsearches.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BOOKMARK_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.bookmarks.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BOOKMARK_LOCATIONS_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.bookmarks.locations.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "COMMIT_SHA", "\"" + getBuildVersion().toString() + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TEST_USERNAME", "\"" + System.getenv("test_user_name") + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TEST_PASSWORD", "\"" + System.getenv("test_user_password") + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DEPICTS_PROPERTY", "\"P180\""

            dimension 'tier'
        }

        beta {
            applicationId 'fr.free.nrw.commons.beta'

            // What values do we need to hit the BETA versions of the site / api ?
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_API_POTD", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=featuredfeed&feed=potd&feedformat=rss&language=en\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_API_HOST", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/w/api.php\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_API_HOST", "\"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_URL", "\"https://www.wikidata.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_FORGE_API_HOST", "\"https://tools.wmflabs.org/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIMEDIA_CAMPAIGNS_URL", "\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commons-app/campaigns/master/campaigns_beta_active.json\""
            buildConfigField "String", "IMAGE_URL_BASE", "\"https://upload.beta.wmflabs.org/wikipedia/commons\""
            buildConfigField "String", "HOME_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "COMMONS_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "WIKIDATA_URL", "\"https://www.wikidata.org\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MOBILE_HOME_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SIGNUP_LANDING_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CreateAccount&returnto=Main+Page&returntoquery=welcome%3Dyes\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SIGNUP_SUCCESS_REDIRECTION_URL", "\"https://commons.m.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&welcome=yes\""
            buildConfigField "String", "FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL", "\"https://commons.wikimedia.beta.wmflabs.org/wiki/Special:PasswordReset\""
            buildConfigField "String", "PRIVACY_POLICY_URL", "\"https://github.com/commons-app/commons-app-documentation/blob/master/android/Privacy-policy.md\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CONTRIBUTION_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.contributions.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "MODIFICATION_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.modifications.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CATEGORY_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.categories.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "RECENT_SEARCH_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.explore.recentsearches.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BOOKMARK_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.bookmarks.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "BOOKMARK_LOCATIONS_AUTHORITY", "\"fr.free.nrw.commons.beta.bookmarks.locations.contentprovider\""
            buildConfigField "String", "COMMIT_SHA", "\"" + getBuildVersion().toString() + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TEST_USERNAME", "\"" + System.getenv("test_user_name") + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "TEST_PASSWORD", "\"" + System.getenv("test_user_password") + "\""
            buildConfigField "String", "DEPICTS_PROPERTY", "\"P245962\""

            dimension 'tier'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'tier'


    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildToolsVersion buildToolsVersion
}

if (isRunningOnTravisAndIsNotPRBuild) {
    play {
        track = "alpha"
        userFraction = 1
        serviceAccountEmail = System.getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME")
        serviceAccountCredentials = file("../play.p12")

        resolutionStrategy = "auto"
        outputProcessor { // this: ApkVariantOutput
            versionNameOverride = "$versionNameOverride.$versionCode"
        }
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try removing

```
    androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was invalid **closure function syntax**.

Please recheck your custom functions syntax in `gitutils.gradle` file.